# what different between the ‘at postgraduate level' and 'in postgraduate level'?

Tags: prepositions

what different between the ‘at postgraduate level' and 'in postgraduate level'?

which one is correct? Is that have the same meaning in two different preposition situation.

Comment: Please note that this site is not the place to learn basic English - instead, I recommend you try our other site [ell.se]. Be sure to use the "search" function first, to see if there's already an answer to your question. :-)

Comment: emm,I have already to search on other site.I know the distinguish between ‘at’ and 'in' in generally situation. but I have  confused what exactly different between ‘at postgraduate level' and 'in postgraduate level'? because someone told me that's ok for  two different preposition expression.

Comment: We don't use "in XX level", it's the wrong preposition. In most ordinary non-idiomatic situations, you can't be "in" a level.